# Caching the pages pointed by Delicious bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks, delicious

Today I accessed an old Delicious bookmark only to find that the page has gone away.

Is there any service which would keep a cached copy of my delicious bookmarks, so I can always access it?

<sub>The page in question was found in Google's cache, but I consider it sheer luck.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using [mypagehub.com](http://mypagehub.com) service. I also usually post relevant links in twitter and this service helps me keeping all links (from delicious and twitter) in one place with full-text search on pages contents, cache storing, etc. But you are free to only integrate it with delicious.

Try it out - you might like it.

Comment: Oh, and it's free!

Comment: Service no longer available (at least not at that URL) at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can still find it on Google Cache and it is just the one page you want simply copy and paste it in Notepad (Editor on Mac) and then save it as a HTML file.

Comment: so essentially "roll your own"

Comment: @Midhat yes but what is the page?

Comment: @benny darksleep.com/lucene

Comment: @Midhat and the Google Cache URL too please?

Comment: @Midhat found it email me at ben@bens-wiki.co.cc and I will send you the HTML file

Comment: @benny thanks a lot for your help. i did that too some time ago. but the point was to keep the pages along with the bookmarks on the web, accessible from anywhere. I guess i could put together a script to grab all pages that exist and and put them to my dropbox. should work for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a service called [historio.us](http://historio.us/). It's like Google for your bookmarks including a cache feature that will be kept for you indefinitely. It lacks though some of the soshul features of delicious you might like.